# In java hibernate can you have a model that is not an entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model

I am getting this error when I try to compile `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.core.model.Team.members[com.core.model.User]`

My model is called User and it is used to combine two other models, one that gets data from keycloak and the other that gets data from Postgres.  This table does not use @entity because it is not attached to a table.  Is there something I am missing.

Here is the code

```
@Data
public class User {

   @NonNull
    private KeycloakUser keycloakUser;
 
    private OtherUser otherUser;

    public User(@NonNull KeycloakUser keycloakUser, @NonNull OtherUser otherUser) {
        this.keycloakUser = keycloakUser;
        this.otherUser = otherUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. The error is pretty straightfoward: do you want for `com.core.model.User`s in the `Team.members` collection to be persisted in your DB using JPA? If so, annotate `User` with `@Entity`. If not, make `Team.members` `@Transient` and strip the `@OneToMany` JPA is complaining about. If I misunderstood the question somehow, please explain what you mean by a 'model that is not an entity'.

Comment: @crizzis thanks, you asking the questions helped me focus in on where to find the issue.  Haven't found it yet, but at least have a better idea of where to look

Answer (score 0):

You must have a model that is not an entity. Your model classes have to be separated from entities.

```
class User {
             
  private KeycloakUser keycloakUser;
             
  private OtherUser otherUser;
             
}

User user = new User();
userService.saveUser(user);

// UserService

void saveUser(User user) {
    UserEntity userEntity = userMapper.toUserEntity(user.getOtherUser());
    userRespository.save(userEntity);

    CreateUserRequest request = userMapper.toCreateUserRequest(user.getKeycloakUser());
    keyCloakClient.createUser(request);
}

// UserMapper

UserEntity toUserEntity(OtherUser user) {
    UserEntity result = new UserEntity();
    result.setName(user.getName());

    return resut;
}
```